# What are the vulnerabilities of using search bar with a NoSQL database for an online app?

Tags: injection, nosql

I am learning web security I have to audit a searchbar on a test website which looks like site.truc.fr:5006/ for a contest. It seems the query function is hardcoded in the webpage

```
    function makeSearch(searchInput) {
        if(searchInput.length == 0) {
            alert("You must provide at least one character!");
            return false;
        }

        var searchValue = btoa('{ allCooks (filter: { firstname: {like: "%'+searchInput+'%"}}) { nodes { firstname, lastname, speciality, price }}}');
        var bodyForm = new FormData();
        bodyForm.append("search", searchValue);

        fetch("index.php?search="+searchValue, {
            method: "GET"
        }).then(function(response) {
            response.json().then(function(data) {
                data = eval(data);
                data = data['data']['allCooks']['nodes'];
                $("#results thead").show()
                var table = $("#results tbody");
                table.html("")
                $("#empty").hide();
                data.forEach(function(item, index, array){
                    table.append("<tr class='table-dark'><td>"+item['firstname']+" "+ item['lastname']+"</td><td>"+item['speciality']+"</td><td>"+(item['price']/100)+"</td></tr>");
                });
                $("#count").html(data.length)
                $("#count").show()
            });
        });
    }
```

I know it means that I can send POST requests to the server using btoa encoding. I know that it looks like a noSQL database. But as far as a flag is hidden there, how can I get control of the server to make i show it to me?

I am only looking for advises.

Comment: From the look of things, it would appear that the server will just run _any_ query you give it.  Which is massively insecure.  You could potentially query any "table" for any data.  For that matter, depending on the mechanism they use to run this, it may also give you write access.  I don't know NoSQL, but if I saw something like this with a traditional RDBMS I'd be looking to see if there's an equivalent to the [catalog views](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/object-catalog-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: *how can I get control of the server* - it is nt clear what you mean.

Comment: @mentallurg I know there is a flag there and I am trying to learn how the database is working to make it do what I want (show me the flag)/ take control of the server